# Making Arrays in c++

Tags: c++

```
    int a[size] ; 

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Player here is your card" << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        if (a = 1)
        {
            cout << "Your Bingo numbers are: 12, 5, 32, 18, 50, 46, 2, 29, 1, 30" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 2)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 43, 1, 6, 34, 8, 19, 23, 42, 41, 5" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 3)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 12, 5, 22, 45, 50, 13, 3, 8, 35, 18" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 4)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 34, 50, 1, 6, 21, 39, 8, 49, 9, 19" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 5)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 30, 14, 7, 28, 43, 34, 37, 48, 49, 18" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 6)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 12, 9, 10, 41, 50, 37, 11, 29, 2, 7, 47" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 7)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 15, 6, 35, 27, 8, 11, 32, 9, 39, 23" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 8)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 48, 21, 3, 9, 2, 32, 50, 31, 13, 38" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 9)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 20, 49, 28, 10, 8, 7, 14, 46, 19, 34" << endl;
        }
        else if (a = 10)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 18, 26, 43, 5, 27, 45, 38, 50, 2, 29" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Not a valid option" << endl;
        }

int b [size];

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Player 2 here is your card" << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        if (b = 1)
        {
            cout << "Your Bingo numbers are: 12, 5, 32, 18, 50, 46, 2, 29, 1, 30" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 2)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 43, 1, 6, 34, 8, 19, 23, 42, 41, 5" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 3)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 12, 5, 22, 45, 50, 13, 3, 8, 35, 18" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 4)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 34, 50, 1, 6, 21, 39, 8, 49, 9, 19" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 5)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 30, 14, 7, 28, 43, 34, 37, 48, 49, 18" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 6)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 12, 9, 10, 41, 50, 37, 11, 29, 2, 7, 47" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 7)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 15, 6, 35, 27, 8, 11, 32, 9, 39, 23" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 8)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 48, 21, 3, 9, 2, 32, 50, 31, 13, 38" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 9)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 20, 49, 28, 10, 8, 7, 14, 46, 19, 34" << endl;
        }
        else if (b = 10)
        {
            cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 18, 26, 43, 5, 27, 45, 38, 50, 2, 29" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Not a valid option" << endl;
        }
```

I need help with this array.  I am not good with arrays and need help.  I do not know how arrays work that good since my book does not explain them.  And wouldn't the all the numbers just print out unless I had two equals signs in my if and else if statements?

Comment: Shouldn't `a` be an `int` in this code (and all of those `=`  be `==` ? What is the title of your beginner's C++ text that doesn't explain arrays, so I know what to put on my ever-expanding never-suggest list?

Comment: Comparing an array to an integer should not compile. If it does then you have stumbled on a bug in your compiler. Does it really compile, and if so, what compiler is this?

Comment: 2 errors in your code: (1) array variable cannot be compared with integer. (2) compare should be "==" instead of "="

Comment: One more error: this code is much too long. When you are playing with a new tool, *start simple.* Write the simplest program you can think of that uses an array, get that working perfectly, then add complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the if statement comparing the array and int. All you need to do is to modify to use the correct equal comparison symbol and use the correct form of array as per the below;

```
if (a[0] == 1)
{
    cout << "Your Bingo numbers are: 12, 5, 32, 18, 50, 46, 2, 29, 1, 30" << endl;
}
else if (a[0] == 2)
{
    cout << "Your bingo numbers are: 43, 1, 6, 34, 8, 19, 23, 42, 41, 5" << endl;
}
```

But it really does appears to be that this does not require array at all to accomplish the task. You just need a variable `a` with the type of `int` and then compare as is (a == 1).

```
int a;
```